# Перебои в работе Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql

Привет!

Недавно стал замечать странности в WP на сайте: после массивных запросов в БД сайт некоторое время (2-5 секунд) показывает белую страницу. Да-да, просто белую страницу без заголовков и т.д. Думал, проблема в хостинге - нет, хостер пишет, что с их стороны все чисто. Затем думал, что проблема только у меня - пользователи начали жаловаться. Что это может быть? Сайт довольно-таки "крупный", контента и прочего там достаточно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите логи Apache, чтобы разобраться, почему такая ошибка вылазит, скорее всего какой-то php скрипт работает неправильно.
Советую периодически смотреть логи и анализировать, всё ли хорошо, тогда вы узнаете о проблемах до того, как вам будут жаловаться пользователи.
Исправив все ошибки, у вас перестанет появляться белый экран.

Я в таких случаях делаю вот как:

1. Я стараюсь не использовать плагины, а всё писать сам или копировать код из плагинов и упрощать, чтобы сайт выполнял только те функции, которые мне надо.
2. Ночью, когда на сайте мало посещений, я включаю на сайте дебаг режим и исправляю все предупреждения, как следствие - у меня чистые логи, а если что-то и появляется, то стараюсь как можно скорее исправить.

Answer (score 2):

Получили белую страницу - посмотрите на реальную сетевую активность. В большинстве браузеров - F12 и вкладка network. И смотрите, что там. Варианты - там пустой ответ, там есть ответ, но он "нестандартный" и тому подобное.

Можно ещё culr/wget/httpie по вкусу.

Comment: @KoVadim вкладка network выдала мне 500 ошибку на белом экране. Контент страницы в тот момент был -
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style><script type="text/javascript">if (!hiddenvaluetimerunsum){var hiddenvaluetimerunsum;}hiddenvaluetimerunsum=3;</script></head><body></body></html>

Comment: Вот, 500 ошибка, с этого и нужно начинать. Вот теперь можно смело идти в логи апача и смотреть, что же там случилось.